# How do I open a link in the current tab for my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my popup.html code:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

But when I click the Google link nothing happens. How do I make the link take me to google.com in the current tab?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `chrome.tabs.query` to find the selected tab and update it.

So I would do something like:

popup.html:

```
<div id='clickme'>Google</div>
<script src = 'popupjs.js'></script>
```

popupjs.js:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'http://www.google.com'});
    });
};
```

This uses [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) and [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) to find the current tab id and update it with the url `http://www.google.com`.

Note: You will need the [`tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) permission in your manifest file!

You could then use some CSS to make the div look like a real link, or just change the cursor when hovering over it.